# ios addSubview not scrolling in uiscrollview

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, swift2

Im working in swift 2.0 in Xcode, Im facing an issue, I want to replace/add a subview in a `UIView` in storyboard.

Here's my code:

```
    self.addChildViewController(vc)
    vc.view.frame = childView.frame
    self.container.addSubview(vc.view)
    vc.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

however I successfully adding the `subview` and I have `UIScrollView` in in which my `childView` `UIView` is palced .. but after placing the `subview`, Im unable to scroll the added view with `UIScrollview` but other content is scrolling fine.

How can I replace/add subview in my `childView` in order to work with `UIScrollview`

Answer (score 0):

Set the content size of scrollview with

```
contentSize = CGSize(width: yourwidth, height: contentsizeheight)
```